# How do get the rows between row A and row B in a table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have an event log that contains many rows like:

[image]
[image]

I would like to get back:

```
group                  | text
-----------------------------------------------------
ErB0zyuzRq6DstbP0UdMag | Received: 1
                       | Received: more text
                       | Received: and some more text
```

So essentially I want to group and extract all `text` that occurs between `group` since there is multiple events that can occur between the start and end occurrence of `ErB0zyuzRq6DstbP0UdMag`.

I've tried to partition by number (in this case 36 / 37) but I just cannot seem to win. Any help would be appreciated. The start of each sequence is always labelled with 36 and the end with 37, so I definitely think using WINDOW will work, but no luck so far.

In addition, the contents that I want is always labelled as 25.

Comment: You have timestamps, why not just do a select on date range?

Comment: I need the rollup of the various groups -- so yes, I do select on date range, but that gives me thousands of rows where I still need to somehow filter all the text by grouping

Comment: '36  ErB0zyuzRq6DstbP0UdMag' has a timestamp, '37 ErB0zyuzRq6DstbP0UdMag' has a timestamp. The rows you want have a timestamp between those two. Is that not true?

Comment: Mmm long day, maybe I am being daft... how would I repeat that over millions of rows? FWIW there are other groupings inbetween, but I've managed to limit the dataset to that sample -- the text and grouping that I want. I just cannot for the life of me see how to join the 2. In other queries I could join in the grouping ID and select structs, but this is breaking my brain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT grp, ARRAY_AGG(text ORDER BY ts) AS text
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    LAST_VALUE(IF(label=36, text, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY ts) AS grp
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE label IN (36, 37, 25)
)
WHERE label = 25
GROUP BY grp
```

If to apply to sample / dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 36 label, '2020-06-01 15:54:31.266711 UTC' ts, 'ErB0zyuzRq6DstbP0UdMag' text UNION ALL
  SELECT 25, '2020-06-01 15:55:31.266711 UTC', 'Received: 1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 25, '2020-06-01 15:56:31.266711 UTC', 'Received: more text' UNION ALL
  SELECT 26, '2020-06-01 15:57:31.266711 UTC', 'Received: more text - to ignore' UNION ALL
  SELECT 25, '2020-06-01 15:58:31.266711 UTC', 'Received: and some more text' UNION ALL
  SELECT 37, '2020-06-01 16:54:31.266711 UTC', 'ErB0zyuzRq6DstbP0UdMag' UNION ALL
  SELECT 36, '2020-06-01 16:55:31.266711 UTC', 'XrB0zyuzRq6DstbP0UdMag' UNION ALL
  SELECT 28, '2020-06-01 16:56:31.266711 UTC', 'Received: 2 - to ignore' UNION ALL
  SELECT 25, '2020-06-01 16:57:31.266711 UTC', 'Received: more text 2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 37, '2020-06-01 16:58:31.266711 UTC', 'XrB0zyuzRq6DstbP0UdMag'
) 
SELECT grp, ARRAY_AGG(text ORDER BY ts) AS text
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    LAST_VALUE(IF(label=36, text, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY ts) AS grp
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE label IN (36, 37, 25)
)
WHERE label = 25
GROUP BY grp
```

result is

[image]

Comment: "Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Peak usage: 136% of limit. Top memory consumer(s): sort operations used for analytic OVER() clauses: 100%" :sob: any idea how I can trim things? maybe pass it the group id?

Comment: ^^ happened when I ran it on a much larger dataset (an entire month) :-(

Comment: usually this is resolved by using PARTITION BY within OVER() - but in your example I don't see anything that could be used for this. if you don't have any other fields in your table for this  - you might want to try partition by let's say day or even hour - depends on nature of your data. For example OVER(PARTITION BY DATE(ts) ORDER BY ts) - something like this - hope you got an idea

Comment: Thank you Mikhail, your answer was still correct :-) the partition by gives me an idea since I do have additional columns that I thought might not be useful...so let me try.